# How do I fix Error Syntax error: main.lua:5: unexpected symbol near '20' on love

Tags: lua

might be a dumb beginner question but When I run my code:

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.print("Hello World", 400, 300)
end
function love.load()
20, 20, 60, 20
end
```

it give me the error message:Error

Syntax error: main.lua:5: unexpected symbol near '20'

Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'

[C]: at 0x7fff3e0d31d0

[C]: in function 'require'

[C]: in function 'xpcall'

[C]: in function 'xpcall'

I just wanna add values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 5 contains a syntax error, like the error says.

If your intent was to return a list from the `love.load` function, you need something like:

```lua
function love.load()
  return {20, 20, 60, 20}
end
```

Comment: To extend on that answer: `love.load` by default is being called in the [run loop](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.run) and does not expect return values.

Answer (score 3):

In Lua writing meaningless literals like that are not accepted, you need to know what you want to do with those numbers, do you want to print them? Store them in a variable? Call another function with them?